# ASP.NET Core IdentityUser relations

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

How can I add a related object to the database?

My IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
}
```

My Todo model:

```
public class Todo 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I have a WebAPI like /api/todos.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]string name)
{
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   // _db is IdentityDbContext that I use
   var newTodo = new Todo() { Name = "do the laundry" }; // Do I have to specify the user like User = user?
   _db.Todos.Add(newTodo);
   await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
   return CreatedAt(...);
}
```

Question: Am I doing it right? Do I have to pass the user to the new Todo item?

Can I somehow add the todo like that?:

```
user.Todos.Add(newTodo);
```

But how would I save it?

Comment: Yes, you do have to pass the user. Have you tried adding the user and running the code? It looks fine at first glance.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley Do you mean it should look like `new Todo() { Name = "do the laundry" , User = user };` ?

Comment: You can do that or add it to the User Todo list and then call update on the user and save changes. Have you tried these yet? That should be what you do first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the User:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var newTodo = new Todo() { Name = "do the laundry", User = user };
_db.Todos.Add(newTodo);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

or add to the user and update it:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var newTodo = new Todo() { Name = "do the laundry" };
user.Todos.Add(newTodo);
_db.Users.Update(user);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Either way should be fine.